# The form reappears as if I had not submitted anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have the Shovell source code from Simply Rails 2 and it used to work. But since I've uninstalled everything, tried to program desktop apps for a while, and reinstalled everything, it doesn't work.

I go to shovell:3000->session->new and then submit something. Then I go to shovell:3000->session (but not ->new) and the URL is loaded as if I hadn't submitted anything.

Comment: I used "ruby script/console" instead of "irb", then tried to save a User record, then it worked instead of giving me an unitialized constant NameError!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code we can only speculate and suggest ways you can attempt to diagnose the problem.

As far as I can tell one of three things is happening:

1. The session is not being saved.
2. You're not filtering for a logged in user.
3. You're going to the sessions controller for no good reason.

If it's the former, you can take a look at the development.log to figure out what actions are being called and whether or not they're successful. If you're just submitting gibberish then there's no reason for the session to be saved. A new session will only be created when a user is authenticated.

To make sure it's not the second problem you should ensure that controllers/views/layouts contain `current_user` or `logged_in?`

Assuming your using the Restful Authentication plugin, there really shouldn't be any views associated with the sessions controller. You might just be seeing the standard layout.